# How to handle resize event with a resize bar?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I've create a simple example for my question and its on [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxTUw/). 
Basically I want to have two things:

1. reflow the size of the chart to fit its container when window is resizing;
2. reflow the size of chart to fit its container when the resize bar is moving

Note: I am using [jQuery UI layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) for layout management and I have no clue how to handle resize event with a moving resize bar.

I've working on this for long and still looking for answers about this. Thanks anyone providing comments or suggestions.

Comment: The jsFiddle example you have is a resizer that doesn't drag. It just resizes when i click on it. is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, problems on jsFiddle maybe, it did work on my project, but when I try to recreate it on jsFiddle it does not work for the exactly same parameter setting. But the clicking resize also explains my question, if it can handle my clicking resize situation, then it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK So to trigger a resize event in JQuery UI Layout, you can trigger an event for either the whole layout, or for each piece of the layout.

Using your jsFiddle example... the west layout resizing the view can be triggered like this:

```
myLayout = $('body').layout({
// ...
west__onresize: function () {
    alert('only when west layout is redrawn') },
```

The whole layout can be triggered like this:

```
myLayout = $('body').layout({
// ...
onresize: function () {
    alert('whenever anything on layout is redrawn.') },
```

These will be hit whenever any of the views resize. this includes window resize events then too.

Comment: interestingly, it works when we resize the south pane..any way to handle the resizing for both opening and closing the west pane?

Comment: just add `onresize: function () {`. This should fire for both window resize and when you drag the bar.

Comment: Thank u very much! That's a great answer and solution. Though I am still looking for a way to resize the chart without refresh it (just want to make it not to load data every time), but your answer is great enough and was exactly what I am looking for this question.

Comment: Thanks, I've thinking about that however I need to do some calculation there for `setSize()` method. You have any ideas how I can get the value of `west__size`? If I just put `west__size` in my function, it won't be resolved..Thanks for you time!

Comment: This works only if the browser window is resized.  Doesn't work if a divider inside the window is resized.  How to make that work?